# Reveal in Finder from Eclipse Juno/Lion

Tags: osx-lion, eclipse, finder

I just upgraded from Eclipse Indigo on Snow Leopard to Eclipse Juno on Lion. The old system allowed right-click or option-click on the title bar to drop down a menu with a path to the current file. (This feature dates back to Mac OS 8 and is common to most document-oriented apps.) The new one seems to lack any Reveal in Finder option and I have to navigate on my own.

How can I get the functionality back? Did I miss something?

Comment: I don't know about Macs, but under Windows, the commercial MyEclipse plugin for Eclipse has a useful "Open in Explorer" context option for files which opens a (Windows) Explorer instance for the folder containing that file. There might be an equivalent for Macs, or, if all else fails, you might be able to add that functionality to Eclipse yourself if you're willing to dig a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the EasyShell plugin (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell). It lets you open Paths in the Finder or a Shell.

Just install it via "Help -> Eclipse Market Place".

If you dont have the Marketplace (eg. because you have the ADT Version). Install it via "Help -> Install new Software" search for "Market Place".

see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16562605/383658

If you only want the Open in Finder option you could use the ExploreFS plugin from Markus Juninger which also works under Juno on osx.

You can find it and instructions here:
http://www.junginger.biz/eclipse/

Basically:

- goto Help -> Install new Software
- use the above as url
- selecte ExploreFS and install
- restart eclipse

Found it thru this mentions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14788278/383658

Comment: Thanks, i'm not using eclipse any more but this sounds perfect. Have some rep!